# AngularJS ng-models using prototype variables within a repeater

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The best way to explain this issue is by example, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YWVDK/

**Javascript**

```
String.prototype.status = {active:false}
String.prototype.name = 'Testing';

var test = function($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [];

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.rows.push(new String('test'));
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
    <table ng-controller="test">
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="button" ng-click="add()">Add</button></td></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.status.active"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Essentially, I would like to bind the checkbox to the row's prototype properties (in this case, *active*).

As you can see, if you click the add button a couple of times and attempt to tick one of the entries, *all* entries are ticked. This only occurs when using ngModel on a property introduced manually into the prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the prototype's property ***is shared by all instances*** and `ng-model` is two way data-binding, when you check on 1 entry, the property is updated and all entries are also updated because they're all watching on the same property.

Comment: yeah that makes a lot of sense, thanks for pointing that out (other replies also).

Answer (score 0):

When you add property on `prototype` of function, it's shared property. You have to add 'active' on each instance during creation. You have to do this:

```
var test = function($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [];

    $scope.add = function() {
        var test = new String('test');
        test.name = 'Testing';
        test.active = true;
        $scope.rows.push(test);
    }
}
```

Working fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/YWVDK/3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting `.status` to an instance of the object `{active:false}` and therefore any update changes that one instance will reflect on all `row`s.

If you set `.status` to a value:

```
String.prototype.status = false
```

and use:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.status"/></td>
```

It would work.  In fact, the easiest solution to your problem is simply **delete** the following line:

```
String.prototype.status = {active:false}
```